# Telegram message search issue with East Asian languages

Tags: search, language, chinese, telegram-messenger

It is a known issue that Telegram message search does not work correctly with East Asian languages (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) or any language that does not use spaces to separate words (see [here](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/1562), [here](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/564), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/7gjcsf/how_to_search_for_telegram_with_a_keyword_gram/). In fact, there is even [a petition for a fix](https://www.change.org/p/www-telegram-org-telegram-to-fix-the-bug-of-chinese-characters-searching)). If one searches for a word or phrase in these languages, only the messages in which the word or phrase searched for is immediately enclosed by special characters or the beginning or end of the entire message on both ends, which is clearly uncommon, show up. I personally verified the issue on the macOS, Android, and web versions of Telegram.

For an ordinary user, besides waiting for Telegram to fix the problem that has been known for years, is there any workaround that is simple enough to search messages in these languages?